# Integer partition refinement, with minimal refinements

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, integer-partitions, extremal-graph-theory

**The setup**

I have two unordered partitions of **N** - example: **25 = 1 + 1 + 4 + 5 + 14** and **25 = 2 + 11 + 12**. On each partitions I can only apply a refinement, which is to further partition one of its partitions (except for **1**), and the goal is to make both partitions equal. So one way to do this would make both partitions **25 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 12**, where in the first partition **14 = 2 + 12** and on the second **2 = 1 + 1** and **11 = 2 + 4 + 5**.

**The problem**

Is there a way to guarantee that we always use the minimal amount of refinements, where we measure the cost by the number of additional "**+**" or sub-partitions? So in the above example, the cost is **4** because we partitions **14** once, **2** once, and **11** twice. But we could have also refined more aggressively so that **25 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 + 5**, but is not minimal. **Alternatively:** Can we calculate the minimal cost with some fast procedure (without knowing the actual partition)?

**A proposed approach - brute force (could be faster?)**

For partition $N_i = \sum_j a_{ij}$.

1. Generate partitions for $a_{ij}=\sum_k b_{ijk}\rightarrow P_{ijm}$.
2. Combine $P_{im} := \wedge_j P_{ijm}$ and sort $P_{im}$.
3. Compare $P_{0m}$ and $P_{1m}$, and only keep equivalent pairs, $P_{m}$
4. Sort by $|P_{m}|$ and use the smallest.

I think that we can potentially improve performance if we isolated step 1 to begin with partitions of size 1 and 2, apply the rest of the steps, calculating some measure of how close we might be to an answer along the way to help prioritise which partitions to check next. Having some idea as to the minimal cost ahead of time (without knowing how) can help in this regard.

Comment: Looks like an NP-hard problem to me but might be wrong.

Comment: @cr001 do you have some intuition as to why?

Comment: The intuition comes from the "tree-like-with-loop" nature of different path this problem takes. That is, the solutions form a directed graph where branches can split or join but no going backward. Not completely, but to me similar to the Knapsack problem in some sense.

Comment: *minimum common integer partition problem*